# How can I download a video given its URL in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, video, download

I have a URL, for example this:

```
https://r6---sn-vgqsrn76.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1566535969&ei=wRxfXezPAoORV-3ogpgK&ip=185.27.134.50&id=o-ALFdSvuvmX_bqDsm4oRW7q9c4igbKlBmECWdISuA4Jxe&itag=22&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mime=video%2Fmp4&ratebypass=yes&dur=624.175&lmt=1529213992430932&fvip=6&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRAIgZzTTsBPpVznwCvzArBFuSF7Bm3yhcO0rwQdfOjBibnsCIBqf8iHuAwahqi0T6qZ3MNbj8BfLgGo2Y3fPOi96RgEV&redirect_counter=1&cm2rm=sn-aigeey7d&req_id=8f890b1c72fda3ee&cms_redirect=yes&mip=2607:fea8:4d9f:fa68:40a2:35d0:8863:2d17&mm=34&mn=sn-vgqsrn76&ms=ltu&mt=1566514280&mv=m&mvi=5&pl=41&lsparams=mip,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl&lsig=AHylml4wRQIgSCcxaGd_IpVykCuglJtHwewUuZZIyKKr1FBbNP5MvqsCIQCYQEUoM9SpfpySHA_13lB6SvevIuMvhyFDEcrsX0y0ig==
```

How can I download the video in this URL programmatically through JavaScript? I cannot use PHP, Apache, JQuery etc, only Pure JavaScript and HTML.

I have tried using download.js, but I do not think that is the right approach to download videos. I have also looked/tried at various other websites and Stack Overflow answers, but none of them fixed this issue.

EDIT: The other SO answer that someone suggested will not work since the video is on a different baseurl than my own, which means that

```
<a href="file" download="filename">
```

will not work on Chrome. Doing this just opens the video.

Comment: Chances are that the answer is that you can't. I don't intend to click on that link to see where it goes, but it probably loads up a full web page that hosts the video, rather than actually loading the video itself. Short of the enormous task of emulating a web browser (or at least a fair portion of web page parsing functionality) in JavaScript, you aren't going to get at the actual video data that way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it loads up to the video itself. If you don't want to click on the video (It's a basketball video) I'll just put a screenshot of that link on Chrome.

Comment: You cannot programatically download a file with JavaScript. This is a security issue -- users don't want to go to websites and have files automatically downloaded without their consent. The best you could do is have an element in an HTML page to click on to initiate the download. There are several answers on SO how to do that.

Comment: That is what I meant, like when the user clicks on a button. The problem is, I've looked at other SO answers, but the file is not a set file; it is dynamic and I get the file's url from another API. I've tried <a download=""> but clicking on that link only takes me to the video page itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I found the solution to the problem. The link was a YouTube source video link that I was trying to download, and on all videos (except the ones with music or the music genre) all you needed to do was to add</strike>

```
&title=[NAME OF FILE HERE]
```

which would download the video.

Edit: Downloading these videos worked with download.js. You need to make a XMLHTTP request to the video to get the data, and then use the function

```
download(data, name, mime)
```

For more documentation, look on the [download.js GitHub page.](https://github.com/rndme/download)

Answer (score 0):

```
function downloadImage() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://via.placeholder.com/150', true);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function () {
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(this.response);
    var tag = document.createElement('a');
    tag.href = imageUrl;
    tag.target = '_blank';
    tag.download = 'sample.png';
    document.body.appendChild(tag);
    tag.click();
    document.body.removeChild(tag);
  };
  xhr.onerror = err => {
    alert('Failed to download picture');
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video

Video Player is loading.Play VideoPlayMuteCurrent Time 0:00/Duration 41:30Loaded: 1.60%00:3900:00Stream Type LIVESeek to live, currently playing liveLIVERemaining Time -41:30 1xPlayback Rate2x1.5x1.25x1x, selected0.75x0.5x0.25xChaptersChaptersDescriptionsdescriptions off, selectedAudio Trackdefault, selectedFullscreenThis is a modal window.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).